# when i call showuser with parameter it will not display result

Tags: mysql

When i call the stored procedure with given parameter, it will resulting into empty table

This is the mysql code for creating and calling stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE showuser(in Id int, in thename varchar(20))
begin
select * from users where id < Id and name = thename;
end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But it will resulting into empty table.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5v1C.png)

Comment: Maybe no records match the values you're providing?  Please provide a [mcve] which includes table definition, data, and attempt to execute the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter names are not case-sensitive, so the name of your `Id` parameter is the same as the name of the `id` column, and the `where id < Id` condition is evaluated as `where id < id` which will never be true, and your query will return nothing!

The simplest way to solve this is to change the parameter name, i.e. `uid`.

Another option is to qualify the column name as the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE showuser(in Id int, in thename varchar(20))
begin
select * from users U where U.id <Id and U.name = thename;
end
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LZPhnKw_)

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the best explanation and also with great example.

Comment: You are welcome, could you check this as an answer to your question.

Comment: yes i checked it and it works. you are right

Comment: NO, I meant to accept my answer by clicking the green checkmark. :)

Comment: ok, ya i did it